# Using text from dynamically created TextBoxes

Tags: c#, user-interface, textbox

I've got a question regarding textboxes in C#. I've made a button that will create textboxes when clicked:

```
    private void helloButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
        TextBox txtRun2 = new TextBox();
        txtRun2.Name = "txtDynamic2" + c++;
        txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic" + c++;
        txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 50 + (20 * c));
        txtRun2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 50 + (20 * c));
        txtRun2.ReadOnly = true;

        txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
        txtRun2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
        this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
        this.Controls.Add(txtRun2);
    }
```

How can I pull the text which the user types into these newly generated textboxes to use it as arguments for a different function (which will be called by a different button)? I'm quite new at this and could use the help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = this.Controls.Find("txtDynamic2", true);
TextBox tx2 = matches[0] as TextBox;            
string yourtext = tx2.Text;
```

This will return an array of controls by the name txtDynamic2,  in your case the first one would be the control you are looking for unless you create more controls having the same name.
This will allow you to fully access the textbox if you found it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtDynamic2", true)[0];
```

Comment: (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtDynamic2", true)(0) should be (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtDynamic2", true)[0]

Comment: oh.. yes, you dont even give me a time to modify? `:D`

Comment: I gave it now, it sometimes happen whimsically :), newbie!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use the instantiated textboxes in other methods then you can achieve that by either passing them to the method, or storing them as members of your class.

Example of storing them in your class below.

```
public class YourForm
{
    private TextBox txtRun;
    private TextBox txtRun2;

    private void helloButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtRun = new TextBox();
        txtRun2 = new TextBox();

        // removed less interesting initialization for readability

        this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
        this.Controls.Add(txtRun2);
    }

    public void DoStuffWithTextBoxes()
    {
        if (txtRun != null && txtRun2 != null)
        {
            // Retrieve text value and pass the values to another method
            SomeOtherMagicMethod(txtRun.Text, txtRun2.Text);
        }
    }

    private void SomeOtherMagicMethod(string txtRunText, string txtRun2Text)
    {
        // Do more magic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily:

```
//get the text from a control named "txtDynamic"
string text = this.Controls["txtDynamic"].Text;
```

Just remember to make sure that your controls have **unique** `Name` property, otherwise You'll get the text from the first control that's found with the specified name.